# Jenkins Pipeline failure reason is at the end of console instead at the step where it occurred

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I'm creating a multi-branch pipeline with a Jenkinsfile and if one step fails I'd like to show the reason in the email that is sent in the post step.

I can fetch the log just fine but my problem is that the failure reason is printed at the end of the console log instead of at the point where it occurred.

If I create a freestyle project then the error messages will always be in the console log where they occurred and the email works as desired.

My Jenkinsfile looks something like this:

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    parameters {
        string(name: 'VERSION', defaultValue: '', description: 'version number to build')
    }
    stages {
        stage("Check parameters") {
            steps {
                script {
                    if (VERSION == null || VERSION == '') {
                        error("Build failed because required parameter VERSION not set")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        stage("Do something") {
            ...
        }
        stage("Rename successful build") {
            steps {
                script {
                    currentBuild.displayName = "v${VERSION}"
                    currentBuild.description = "Successful build for v${VERSION}"
                }
            }
        }
    }
    post {
        failure {
            withFolderProperties {
                echo "Recipients: ${env.MAIL_RECIPIENTS}"
                script {
                    if (env.MAIL_RECIPIENTS) {
                        emailext (
                            to: env.MAIL_RECIPIENTS,
                            replyTo: '$DEFAULT_REPLYTO',
                            subject: '$DEFAULT_SUBJECT',
                            body: '$DEFAULT_CONTENT',
                            mimeType: 'text/html'
                        );
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This will generate the following console log if I start the build without a version parameter.

This is just an example and the same persists if another stage fails at some point (I cleaned some of the [Pipeline] lines):

```
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] withEnv
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Check parameters)
[Pipeline] script
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] error
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // script
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (build)
Stage "Do Something" skipped due to earlier failure(s)
...
Stage "Rename successful build" skipped due to earlier failure(s)
...
Sending email to: xxx
...
ERROR: Build failed because required parameter VERSION not set
Finished: FAILURE
```

The last two lines are missing in the email because it is sent before they are printed; however, why is the ERROR printed at the end of the log instead of at the step where it occurred? Is there a way where i can configure this?

I'm expecting that the error is printed before the next step is shown in the log.

Answer (score 1):

Your expectation can be easily achieved with Jenkins scripted pipeline but a little difficult with Jenkins declarative pipeline.

but In the Declarative pipeline, If you are raising an Error based on some condition you know what could be the error at the end of the build, so while you raising the error you could grab the error string in a variable and make use of it in the failure stage.

In **Scripted Pipeline**, it would be something like this

```
def isItFail = false
def failureReason = ""
node {
  try {
     stage('check parameter') {
        if (VERSION == null || VERSION == '') {
            throw new RuntimeException("Version number should not be empty")                
        }
     }
     stage('some other stage') {
        .....
     }
  }catch(Exception e ) {
      isItFail = true
      failureReason = e.getMessage()
  }finally {
     if(isItFail) {
       echo "Send An Email with this Text with Reason: ${failureReason}"
     }
  }
}
```

In **Declarative Pipeline**, it would be

```
def failReason = ""

pipeline {
    agent any;
    stages {
        stage('check version') {
            steps {
                script {
                    script {
                        if (VERSION == null || VERSION == '') {
                            failReason = "Build failed because required parameter VERSION not set"
                            error(failReason)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        stage('other stage') {
            ....
        }
    }
    post {
        failure {
            echo "Send An Email with Reason : ${failReason}"
        }
    }
}
```

In the declarative pipeline, there is no any `catch{}` DSL and you can't use `try..catch..finally` outside of `script{}` DSL, hence it little hard to bring the failure reason text to the end of the pipeline

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The problem with the part in the declarative pipeline is that I could only catch the error that I throw myself, but I can't catch the reason for errors that are unexpected in the different stages. I guess I need to take a closer look at the scripted pipeline, but I much rather have the error at the step where it is happening printed in the logfile than at the end and having to catch the errors myself. Is there any way to configure this?